# Trying to append excel file on flutter (excel 2.1.0 package) but its overwriting the file everytime

Tags: android, excel, flutter, dart, append

So i am trying to append a saved excel file without overwriting the existing data.Everytime i try something its just overwrites the file.In the if i check if the file is existing if not than creates it and the next time when clicking a button appends it. Can anyone explain me whats up whit this code? i have started learning flutter/java/dart only a couple weeks now.I have checked the package api document,flutter documentation and i just cant get it why its not working even tho i pass the append file mode in.
i hope i could explain my problem my english is not the best.

```
var excel = Excel.createExcel();
  var sheet = excel.sheets[excel.getDefaultSheet() as String];
  var dir = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/";
  String name = "ExcelTest2.xlsx";
  if (await File(dir + name).exists()) {
    List<String> data = ["data"];
    sheet!.appendRow(data);
    var bytes = excel.save();
    File(join(dir + name))
      ..createSync(recursive: true)
      ..writeAsBytesSync(bytes!, mode: FileMode.append);
    print("appended");
  } else {
    print('File is Being Written To File Sytem');
    sheet!.setColAutoFit(0);
    sheet.setColAutoFit(1);
    sheet.setColAutoFit(2);
    sheet.setColAutoFit(3);
    sheet.setColAutoFit(4);
    sheet.setColAutoFit(5);
    sheet.setColAutoFit(6);
    sheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex: 0, rowIndex: 0)).value = "Date/Time";
    sheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex: 1, rowIndex: 0)).value = "Type";
    sheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex: 2, rowIndex: 0)).value = "data5";
    sheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex: 3, rowIndex: 0)).value = "data4";
    sheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex: 4, rowIndex: 0)).value = "data3";
    sheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex: 5, rowIndex: 0)).value = "data1 ";
    sheet.cell(CellIndex.indexByColumnRow(columnIndex: 6, rowIndex: 0)).value = "data2";
    var filebytes = excel.save();

    File(join(dir + name))
      ..createSync(recursive: true)
      ..writeAsBytes(filebytes!);
  }
```

tried with Future but i can not really get that to work and it is just the same like above (or not?)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide a sample input data that you want to process here and your expected sample output of a smaller scale? Further, what's the quantity of the data that you have on current worksheet/book for you to state that overriding it is slower than dumping the new/processed data?

Comment: Hi thankyou!Essentaly i just want to save strings to an excel file. I the else{} i would create a file with strings in the first row of the excel document,and if the file exist (if{}) than i want to append the extra user input under the first row(under the lets call it Headers) and save the file with the extra strings

Answer (score 0):

You are creating **the instance of a new excel file** and then trying to append it which results in overwriting the existing file instead of appending it.

Instead of doing `var excel = Excel.createExcel();` You should **read** your **existing file** and then **append** it.

[Read Section "Read XLSX File" for more details.](https://pub.dev/packages/excel#append-row)